Find the Real Number $ k $for which the Parabola Intersects the X-Axis at a Given Range
I am working on a problem where I need to find the real number ( k ) such that the parabola described by the equation
$[ y = -x^2 + kx + k - \frac{5}{4} ]$
has an x-intercept $A(m, 0)$ where $-2 \leq m \leq 1$
Given that one of the solutions (roots) of the equation is ( m ), how do I determine the corresponding values of ( k ) that satisfy this condition?
Additional Information:

$ y = -x^2 + kx + k - \frac{5}{4} = 0 $
One of the roots is ( m )
$ -2 \leq m \leq 1 $

How can I find ( k ) in terms of ( m ) and ensure it is valid within the specified range?

How far did you get with this problem? I think the first step is quite clear: Solve for $k$ using the first equation. You get two results, and then you have to figure out how to make it so that at least one of them is in the range $(-2,1)$.

Just solve for y = 0, x = m. This gives you a quadratic in m and you can solve for m in terms of k. Use the given inequality to obtain the range of k.

Thank you for your guidance. I have set ( y = 0 ) and ( x = m ), resulting in the quadratic equation:
$[ -m^2 + km + k - \frac{5}{4} = 0 ]$
Solving for ( k ), I get:
$[ k = \frac{m^2 + \frac{5}{4}}{m + 1} ]$
However, I am unsure about how to proceed from here to obtain the range of ( k ) that ensures at least one root is within the range ((-2, 1)). Could you provide more details or a step-by-step approach on how to apply the given inequality to determine the valid range of ( k )?

@Matti P. Thank you for your response. I have already used the quadratic formula to express
in terms of
, and I understand that this will yield two results. However, I am unsure about the next steps required to ensure that at least one of these roots is in the range
(−2,1). Could you provide further guidance on how to approach this part of the problem?

Starting with the first equation with $k$ as a parameter,
$$
-x^2 +kx+ \left( k - \frac{5}{4} \right) = 0
$$
we can use the quadratic formula to find the $x$-coordinates of the roots:
$$
x = \frac{
 - k \pm \sqrt{
k^2 +4\left( k - \frac{5}{4} \right)
}}{
-2
} = \frac{1}{2} \left( k \pm \sqrt{k^2 +4k -5} \right)
$$
Now, we want to find the value of $k$ so that at least one of those values is in the range $(-2,1)$. Starting with the plus-signed, we get
$$
-2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( k + \sqrt{k^2 +4k -5} \right) \leq 1
$$
or
$$
-4 \leq  k +\sqrt{k^2 +4k -5}  \leq 2
$$

The left-hand side gives us $-4 \leq  k + \sqrt{k^2 +4k -5} \Rightarrow k \geq 1$ or $k \leq -21/5$ (a few steps omitted here)
The right-hand side gives us $k +\sqrt{k^2 +4k -5}  \leq 2 \Rightarrow 1 \leq k \leq \frac{9}{8}$ or $k \leq -5$ (a few steps omitted here as well)
We need both of these to be true at the same time, the intervals where this happens is $k \leq -21/5$ and $1 \leq k \leq \frac{9}{8}$

Then for the minus-signed solution ...

Left-hand side gives us $-4 \leq  k - \sqrt{k^2 +4k -5} \Rightarrow k \geq 1$
Right-hand side gives us $k - \sqrt{k^2 +4k -5} \leq 2 \Rightarrow k \geq 1$ or $k \leq -5$
The intersection of these two is just $x\geq 1$

The final set is the union of these two sets, resulting in
$$
k \leq -21/5 \qquad \text{or} \qquad k \geq 1
$$

Thank you for the detailed explanation! It helped clarify the process significantly.
